# Must you write the full name of a person in the death note to kill them?

Tags: death-note

So let's say I wanted to kill, for example, David Connor with the death note. But his full name would be David Winston Connor. Must I write his full name, or is David Connor enough?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

David Connnor should be enough, in [How to Use I](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note#How_to_Use:_I) it says

> This note will not take effect unless the writer has the person's face in their mind when writing his/her name. Therefore, people sharing the same name will not be affected.

That alone should be enough. if, by some genetic miracle, 2 identical people with the same name existed then adding the person's full name (ie. Troy Delu vi La'Flash) may then allow the Death Note tell the difference between the 2.

**IF**, and this is a huge if, that 2 identical people with identical full names existed then it's quite possible they will be immune unless the cause of death was

> David Winston Connor dies from a heart attack in 40 seconds **after writing his own name in the death note**

but try and get someone to do that, also the odds of 2 people like that being born is insanely huge.

NOTE: To clarify a point raised by trlkly, [How to Use: LIII](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note#How_to_Use:_LIII) talks about writing one's *name* across multiple pages, Point 1 says it wont work but Point 2 says that the front and back are still one page and talks about writing the surname on the front and given name in the back. this seems to imply that by *name* it would refer to the *given* and *surname*.

Comment: > the odds of 2 people like that being born is insanely huge

True. But then face alteration and 'Plastic surgery' are not out of bounds!

Comment: If they would be immune, all people in a criminal organization should officially change their names to the same name and do plastic surgery for the same face. They would rule Light's new world.

Comment: This would imply you could just write someone's first name and have it work, as long as you knew their face. I mean, there are multiple people with the name David, but I'm picturing a specific David. That would seem to work by what you say.

Comment: @GauravAgarwal i don't think even with Plastic surgery you could get a 100% replication, and even then it would still have to be a stroke of luck to have the exact same name as the person you're trying to become, not to mention the time and money it'll take leaving a window of opportunity.

Comment: @PeterRaeves i feel so sorry for an organization who names everyone "David Winston Connor" and forces them to all look identical, be hell when it comes to giving payment, also imagine the orders! *"David, can you take David and David and pick up David's team before the Police bust them, we don't need them revealing David's safe house, otherwise she'll be pissed off at us for letting it happen"* (yes, i'm plying that they would make a woman into David)

Comment: @trlkly [How to Use: LIII, Point 2](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note#How_to_Use:_LIII) *But the front and back of a page is considered as one page. For example, the Death Note will still take effect if you write the victim's surname on the front page and given name on the back.* i think it implies that by "name" it means first and surname. i'll be sure to add it in my answer just to clarify

Answer (score 8):

I think David Connor should be enough as the death note requires you to know the name of the person AND know the face of the person. 
So as long as you have the face in your head, the middle name is not important.